# RestKit SerializationMimeType - does it deserialize using the same type?

Tags: objective-c, ios, serialization, deserialization, restkit

When you set `serializationMIMEType` for your `RKObjectManager`, does it apply to how objects are de-serialized or only to how they are serialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they are deserialized depending on the mime type in the header of the response. Can't test this at the moment hence the *think*.